# cql-import tool not present in sqoop 1.4.6

Tags: cassandra, sqoop, cql

I am currently stuck on Data migration, I want to migrate data from Oracle Database to Cassandra.

I have following tools installed on Linux

> 1. DSE 4.8
> 2. Hadoop 2.7.3
> 3. Sqoop 1.4.6

I am not sure why my SQOOP version is not having **cql-import** or any cassandra related commands.

Following are the available commands I can see in the "SQOOP help" output

Available commands:

```
  codegen      
  create-hive-table 
  eval     
  export    
  help              

  import     
  import-all-tables 
  import-mainframe  
  job      
  list-databases    
  list-tables       
  merge             
  metastore         

  version
```

I have searched throughout the net and found following link having latest sqoop version, but cql-import tool is missing in all of them.

https://www-eu.apache.org/dist/sqoop/

http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/apache/sqoop/1.4.6/

It would be very helpful if any one has the link for a sqoop version which supports cassandra data migration commands like **"cql-import"**.

Editted:
One more point to add, I have manually configured Hadoop and Sqoop.

Thanks in advance

Comment: you need to start dse node with analytics enabled

Comment: It is actually in analytics mode.
Here is the nodetool status output  
Datacenter: Analytics
=====================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address         Load       Tokens  Owns    Host ID                               Rack
UN  xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx  838.57 KB  256     ?       9ae853d0-743b-4564-9685-9e57b1fdc13b  rack1

Comment: if it is in analytics mode then you can use `dse sqoop cql-import`....

Comment: Also when I check SQOOP_HOME/bin i.e. /etc/dse/sqoop/bin I dont see any file like sqoop-cql-import. Where I can see other command files like sqoop-list-tables, sqoop-import

Comment: Note: `cql-import` is not available in sqoop... it is functionality of datastax enterprise... and is deprecated in latest version

Comment: Is it deprecated in dse 4.8?

Comment: When I run below command
dse sqoop cql-import \
--connect jdbc:URL \
--username swmain -P  \
--table test_table \
--cassandra-keyspace keyspace_name \
--cassandra-table test_table \
--cassandra-row-key test_col \
--cassandra-host hos-ipt \
--cassandra-create-schema

I get following message: No such sqoop tool: cql-import. See 'sqoop help'.

Comment: Am I missing something in DSE or SQOOP installation.? Has anyone faced similar issue that I am getting "No such sqoop tool: cql-import." Error even when I am in Analytics mode.?